# R apply correlation function to a list

Tags: r, list, function

I have a data frame like this:

```
set.seed(1)
category <- c(rep('A',100), rep('B',100), rep('C',100))
var1 = rnorm(1:300)
var2 = rnorm(1:300)
df<-data.frame(category=category, var1 = var1, var2=var2)
```

I need to calculate the correlations between var1 and var2 by category. I think I can first `split` the `df` by `category` and apply the `cor` function to the list. But I am really confused about hot to use the `lapply` function.
Could someone kindly help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should produce the desired result:

```
lapply(split(df, category), function(dfs) cor(dfs$var1, dfs$var2))
```

EDIT:

You can also use `by` (as suggested by @thelatemail):

```
by(df, df$category, function(x) cor(x$var1,x$var2))
```

Comment: @thelatemail, True, I used `lapply` because OP seems to be more familiar with `split` and `lapply` functions. So, It would be easier to understand the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` to get the same but as a vector, not a list

```
sapply(split(df, category), function(dfs) cor(dfs$var1, dfs$var2))
```

Answer (score 1):

And just for comparison, here's how you'd do it with the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(category) %>% summarize(cor=cor(var1,var2))

#   category         cor
# 1        A -0.05043706
# 2        B  0.13519013
# 3        C -0.04186283
```